# MPAndroidChart specify values on X-axis and scaling axises to the screen

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I use the Amazing MPChart, however i have trouble setting other than index values
on on the X-Axis.
Do anyone know how to set it, should i modify labels of the axis?
The documentation say that the x-value is set in the data object, bit
X-values is always and index, as far as i can see.

My goal is to have values of time on the x-axis, statistics for 1 week 2 weeks one month etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using these line of code. You can understand this code if you are familiar with mpchartlibrary android.

```
ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
xVals.add("1 week");
xVals.add("1 Month");
data= new LineData(xVals, setData);
mChart.setData(data);
```